# How to Capitalize the First Letter of the Kendo-DatePicker format in Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, format, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo-datepicker and it's always displaying the format in the field like following.
[image]

But I want to customize this as **Month/Day/Year**. Capitalize the first letter. Is it possible to customize like this.

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

    <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date</label>
    
     <div class="col-sm-4">
    
         <kendo-datepicker formControlName="startingDate" format="MM/dd/yyyy">
         </kendo-datepicker>
    
      </div>
 </form>
```

**.ts**

```
myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    startingDate: new FormControl(""),
  });
```

Comment: Does Kendo-datepicker have a placeholder attribute you can edit? Just a thought, I have never used it before.

Comment: Hi @Micah. Yes when I add placeholder it works, but still this this format (month/day/year) is also displaying. (Displaying both placeholder and format) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by overriding the **k-input** CSS class.

```
 :host::ng-deep .k-input {
        text-transform: capitalize;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would override css for date input. Something like this:

```
.k-dateinput > .k-input-inner {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Working example: [Capitalize date format in form group](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpu4yc?file=src/styles.css)

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: Yes it does, check the working example in the answer.

Comment: I need to use .k-input class to override. Then it's worked. Thanks for the help !